# Why do I get an error for incorrect number of arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

I have:

```
import datetime
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, dob, carnivore):
        self.__dob = dob
        self.__carnivore = carnivore

    @property
    def dob(self):
        return self.__dob

    @dob.setter
    def dob(self, dob):
        self.__dob = dob

    @property
    def carnivore(self):
        return self.__carnivore

    @carnivore.setter
    def carnivore(self, carnivore):
        self.__carnivore = carnivore

    def __str__(self):
        return "DOB: " + str(self.__dob) + "\nCarnivore: " + str(self.__carnivore)
```

My second  class:

```
import Species.Animal as Animal
import datetime as date


class Amphibian(Animal):

    def __init__(self, dob=date.datetime.now(), carnivore=False, *characteristics):
        super(Animal, self).__init__(dob, carnivore)
        self.__characteristics = []
        for characteristic in characteristics:
            self.__characteristics.append(characteristic)

    @property
    def characteristics(self):
        return self.__characteristics

    @characteristics.setter
    def characteristics(self, characteristic):
        self.__characteristics.append(characteristic)

    def __str__(self):
        characteristics = ""
        for characteristic in self.__characteristics:
            characteristics += str(characteristic)
        return characteristics
```

Using:

```
amphibian = Amphibian(date.date(1979, 1, 12), True, "BackBone", "Cold Blooded")
print(amphibian)
```

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Daniel/PycharmProjects/ObjectOrientedSpecies/Species/Amphibian.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       class Amphibian(Animal): TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

I am new to Python so I'm not sure what good OO Practices are.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I can see. Firstly you should call `super` on the class name of the class you are calling `super` in (that is a bit of a mouthful) so that line should be `super(Amphibian, self).__init__(dob, carnivore)` and *not* `super(Animal, self).__init__(dob, carnivore)`. Python will find the baseclass `Animal` itself.

However the main problem is that the class `Animal` is (almost certainly) in a file called "Animal.py". Python makes a module called `Animal` automagically when it sees a file called "Animal.py" (and does something similar for all other ".py" names. So your class `Animal` is, in fact inside a module called `Animal`.

Therefore when you do `import Species.Animal as Animal` you are importing the *module* not the class inside it. So when you do `class Amphibian(Animal):` your Amphibians are inheriting from the class `module` not from the class `Animal`. You need to change your import to the following to get the class `Animal` instead: `from Species.Animal import Animal`.

In terms of your style I don't really see the point of having lots of decorated getters and setters if there is nothing going on inside them except simple getting and setting. Just get rid of the underscores in front of the atribute names and use them directly. You only need to use the getters and setters if something else has to happen to do the getting and setting.